# How can I make KDevelop break on exceptions?

Tags: c++, kdevelop

I am Debugging some BOOST unit tests in KDevelop and it sadly happened that they crash with an exception. How can I make KDevelop automagically break if any exception is raised? In Visual Studio there is a tick box for this one, is it also available in KDevelop?

In my case, BOOST catches the exception, so the program doesn't technically crash. However, the reported message is not really helpful.

Comment: not yet available, patches welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

As a sort of workaround I figured out that you can put a breakpoint somewhere at the beginning of your code, run in debugger, and after it breaks go to the GDB tab and issue a command directly for gdb:

```
catch throw
```

then click continue, and the compiler will break on exceptions as requested.

I am still looking for a more elegant solution though.